# what is the proper way to set a UIImageView with a UIImage?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView that starts off with an image (loading.png) specified in IB. When my app starts, a new image is downloaded from the internet to replace the existing one. I do the following to replace the image:

```
if(object.imageView.image != nil){

[object.imageView.image release];
object.imageView.image = nil;               
}       
object.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloadedimage.png"];
```

Is this the right way to re-set an image? I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when doing so.

Comment: No -- you don't own the property, so you shouldn't be calling release on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIImageView's [`image` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW1) is declared as

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
```

That means when you set this property, the old value will be automatically `-release`'d. So this 1 line is enough:

```
object.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"downloadedimage.png"];
```